# Route::Resource Was Working Fine, but additional route using same controller got Method Controller::show does not exist. Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, routes, methods, controller

So I created 2 separate index using the same controller, ones where every data is retrieved and other only specific criteria of data is retrieved. Register and Login routes is working fine, every resources routes also working fine, the only problem was when using a new routes with already established route resources controller. and what I got was **BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\PinjamController::show does not exist.**

Links into respective index

```
<!-- /.Index Working Fine -->
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('pinjam.index') }}"> Index Pinjam</a>
<!-- /.This one got error 404 because resource didn't contain 'all' syntax and only focused on CRUD?-->
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('pinjam.all')}}"> Record Peminjaman</a>
<!-- /.This is the one that got badMethodCall error-->
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('/admin/pinjam/all')}}"> Record Peminjaman</a>
```

web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PinjamController;
Route::resource('/admin/pinjam',PinjamController::class)->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/all',[PinjamController::class,'all'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/kembali',[PinjamController::class,'kembali'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::post('/admin/pinjam/track',[PinjamController::class,'track'])->middleware('auth:admin');
```

PinjamController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\bukus_users;
protected function all()
    {
        $rows = bukus_users::query()->with(['buku', 'user'])->paginate(5)->toArray(); // the error part and also where I seperated them was on blade file
        return view('admin.pinjam.all', ['rows' => $rows]);
    }
    protected function kembali()
    {
        return view('admin.kategori.kembali');
    }
    protected function track(Request $request)
    {
        $pinjam = bukus_user::where('barcode','like','%' . request('barcode') . '%')->first();
        $pinjam->status_pengembalian = false;
        $pinjam->save();
        return redirect()->route('pinjam.index')->with('success','Buku Telah dikembalikan');
    }
    protected function index()
    {
        $rows = bukus_users::query()->with(['buku', 'user'])->paginate(5)->toArray(); // index just working fine
        return view('admin.pinjam.index', ['rows' => $rows]);
    }
```

Screenshot of error
[link to ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb8Le.png), so what's the problem here? As resource route works normally, register and login that I created manually to make admin guard just also working fine, so why only additional routes besides resource routes that got error from accessing the same controller?

Comment: Try making the controller methods `public`.

Comment: those "supplemental" routes need to be defined before the resource definition (otherwise the "show" route will catch them) ... and the error is correct, you don't have a `show` method, resource routes generate a route to the `show` method

Comment: @IGP yes this is most probably the issue, do this for all methods. Also giving name to routes is preferrable.

Comment: I tried to put it before resource... now it worked on 'all', but now I have problem with 'kembali'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Reordering routes. Put all new routes before Resourse.

```
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/all',[PinjamController::class,'all'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/kembali',[PinjamController::class,'kembali'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::post('/admin/pinjam/track',[PinjamController::class,'track'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::resource('/admin/pinjam',PinjamController::class)->middleware('auth:admin');
```

Or you can try manually adding resource routes like this

```
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/{pinjam}', [PinjamController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin/pinjam', [PinjamController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/create', [PinjamController::class, 'create'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::post('/admin/pinjam', [PinjamController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin/pinjam/{pinjam}/edit', [PinjamController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::put('/admin/pinjam/{pinjam}', [PinjamController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::delete('/admin/pinjam/{pinjam}', [PinjamController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth:admin');
```